# SPI sending and receiving data

Tags: python-3, spi

I hope you can help.

I am currently using a raspberry pi 4b and want to be able to use the SPI capabilities. For my pi I have SPI0 and SPI1. The pins used are as follows;

```
SPI0_MOSI - pin 19 (BCM_10)
SPI0_MISO - pin 21 (BCM_9)
SPI0_SCLK - pin 23 (BCM_11)
SPI0_CE0  - pin 24 (BCM_8)

SPI1_MOSI - pin 38 (BCM_20)
SPI1_MISO - pin 35 (BCM_19)
SPI1_SCLK - pin 40 (BCM_21)
SPI1_CE0  - pin 12 (BCM_18)
```

For now I am trying to send binary data from one SPI to the other on the same pi, and to display the number received in the terminal or by LEDs on a breadboard.

What would my code look like to achieve this? I am currently using Python-3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know how SPI works? There are numerous libraries and examples if you want to do this but it makes about as much sense as sending data via the moon. Most SPI examples operate as master to communicate with a slave device.

Comment: Wouldn't the look of you code depend on your programming style?

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

A SPI connection has two ends.  One end is the master and controls the clock.  The other end is a slave and responds to the master's clock.

Generally Raspberry Pi's only support master mode so you can not communicate between Pis.

However the Pi does have hardware to support slave mode.  There is no operating system support for this hardware.

pigpio does offer limited support.

https://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html#bsc_xfer

Personally I think you would be better off finding another subject to research.